# SQL: What does KEY id_2 do?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, key

I have been using:

```
PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE id (id), KEY id_2 (id)
```

whenever I create a table, but I dont understand what `KEY id_2 (id)` does and why?

I've searched everywhere and cannot find a suitable answer. Thanks!

Comment: Provide some context. `PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE id (id), KEY id_2 (id)` alone doesn't do anything. Please post the full SQL or context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example, I believe you're creating three different indexes on one column... which probably isn't what you were intending to do.

First, you're creating a primary key:

```
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Next, you're creating a unique index, which isn't necessary, because you already have the primary key... and you name this unique index `id`:

```
UNIQUE id (id)
```

Finally, you create a third index named `id_2`:

```
KEY id_2 (id)
```

Instead, I think you should be creating just the primary key, and forgo the other two indexes.

Comment: Note that if you have three indexes, you are wasting disk space storing two superfluous indexes, and you are slowing down your update operations because three indexes have to be changed, not just one.  So, you're taking a performance hit to no benefit; a single index can do the job.  (Oh, and you're slowing the optimizer; it has to consider which of three identical indexes will be most useful, if any of them are any use.)

Answer (score 1):

From this question: [Why most SQL databases allow defining the same index twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356391/why-most-sql-databases-allow-defining-the-same-index-twice)

It looks like the `KEY` syntax is allowing you to create a named index for that key column. The `id_2` is the name for it. As you'll see in the related quesiton, you can specify this multiple times:

```
CREATE TABLE `testkey` (
  `id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `id_2` (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the name of your index. You're creating an index called id_2 on the id column

Answer (score 0):

It creates an index on the `id` column called `id_2`.

From the [documentation for the MySQL CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) statement:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    { LIKE old_tbl_name | (LIKE old_tbl_name) }

create_definition:
    col_name column_definition   | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] PRIMARY KEY [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...   | {INDEX|KEY} [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
```

In other words, `KEY` is a synonym for `INDEX`.