# Why do I need a name for Mysql's index?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the SQL index name for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191147/what-is-the-sql-index-name-for)

```
create index IDX_testNoPK_Name on testNoPK (name)
```

I mean what is the function of index name ?

Why the index needs a name ?

Answer (score 3):

Indexes need names for the same reasons than everything else (databases, tables, columns, users...): so you can later refer to them.

Some situations where you need a reference to an index include:

- When you violate a restriction and MySQL needs to tell you which one.
- When you generate an explain plan and want to know what indexes are being used.
- When you want to drop the index.

Answer (score 2):

The name is IDX_testNoPK_Name !

```
CREATE INDEX IndexName on TableName (FieldName)
```

Index name are used to read Execution Plan, which says you when an index is used.

The name is print on the Execution Plan, so a good naming convention on Index name will help you to fully understand what your query are doing.

Possible Duplicate : [What is the SQL index name for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191147/what-is-the-sql-index-name-for)

Comment: I know, I mean what is the function of index name? Why the index needs a name?

Answer (score 1):

An index name is required to identify it. Naming an index allows you to execute actions over it as modify, rebuild, shrink.

Without naming indexes can be impossible to create some kind of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

**IDX_testNoPK_Name** is the index Name for your table